# How can I get distance between origin and destination using directions service of google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have two HTML fields with id `origin` and `destination`. I have already added google places API for address predictions and that is working fine. Now I want to take the origin and destination addresses and add Listener on `form's` button when it is clicked. I can retrieve miles without showing the map.

**Here is my Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="border-bottom mb-4 w-100 d-sm-flex">
                <h3 class="text-secondary pb-3">To Your Destination</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="border-bottom mb-4 w-100 d-sm-flex" id="miles">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter pickup location</label>
                <input type="text" id="origin" class="form-control border border-primary" name="origin" autocomplete>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter dropoff location</label>
                <input type="text" id="destination" class="form-control border border-primary" name="destination"
                       autocomplete>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Date and Time</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" name="travel_date_time">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mt-5">
                <button type="button" id="qoute-btn" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Quote Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript code so far. I am missing something because the code is not throwing any exception. I am not able to understand how I can bind the `quote-btn`.

```
function initMap() {
// Initialize the autocomplete objects for origin and destination input fields
    const options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}
    };
    const originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('origin'), options);
    const destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'), options);

// Set the fields to return place details when a user selects a suggestion
    originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']);
    destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']);

// Initialize the directions service
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

// Initialize the directions renderer
//     const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

// Set the directions renderer options
//     directionsRenderer.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true});

// Add a one-time listener to the "directions_changed" event
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(directionsRenderer, 'directions_changed', function () {
        // Get the origin and destination values
        const originValue = document.getElementById('origin').value;
        const destinationValue = document.getElementById('destination').value;

        // Check if the origin and destination values are not null
        if (originValue && destinationValue) {
            // Create the request object for the DirectionsService
            const request = {
                origin: originValue,
                destination: destinationValue,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };

            // Call the DirectionsService to calculate the route
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status) {
                    // Get the distance in miles from the response object
                    const distanceInMiles = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                    console.log(`The distance from ${originValue} to ${destinationValue} is ${distanceInMiles}.`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`Error: ${status}`);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need a form if you're not submitting it... And you are not telling your script anywhere what to do with that quote button (which btw has a spelling mistake in its id in your HTML) so nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

- You don't need an HTML form if you are not submitting it
- You need to register a click event listener on your quote button
- Instead of that you wrote all your directions related code in a `directions_changed` event listener (which is for when a user drags directions on a map) so obviously nothing is going to happen
- You have a typo in the ID of your quote button

What I have changed:

- Put the directions request stuff in a `getDirections()` function
- Register a click event listener on the quote button
- Call the `getDirections()` function when button is clicked
- Removed the form which you don't need
- Added a map if you need one, and if you don't, just delete the lines with the `// Comment below ...` comment

Proof of concept:

```js
let directionsService;
// Comment below if map display is not needed
let directionsRenderer;

function initMap() {

  // Comment below if map display is not needed
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  });

  // Initialize the autocomplete objects for origin and destination input fields
  const options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'uk'
    }
  };
  const originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('origin'), options);
  const destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'), options);

  // Set the fields to return place details when a user selects a suggestion
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']);
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'formatted_address', 'geometry']);

  // Initialize the directions service
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  // Initialize the directions renderer
  // Comment the 2 lines below if map display is not needed
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  
  // Quote button click
  document.getElementById('quote-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

    getDirections();
  });

}

function getDirections() {

  const originValue = document.getElementById('origin').value;
  const destinationValue = document.getElementById('destination').value;

  // Check if the origin and destination values are not null
  if (originValue && destinationValue) {
    // Create the request object for the DirectionsService
    const request = {
      origin: originValue,
      destination: destinationValue,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    // Call the DirectionsService to calculate the route
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status) {
        // Get the distance in miles from the response object
        const distanceInMiles = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        console.log(`The distance from ${originValue} to ${destinationValue} is ${distanceInMiles}.`);
        
        // Comment below if map display is not needed
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        console.log(`Error: ${status}`);
      }
    });
  }
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="border-bottom mb-4 w-100 d-sm-flex">
      <h3 class="text-secondary pb-3">To Your Destination</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="border-bottom mb-4 w-100 d-sm-flex" id="miles">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter pickup location</label>
      <input type="text" id="origin" class="form-control border border-primary" name="origin" autocomplete>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter dropoff location</label>
      <input type="text" id="destination" class="form-control border border-primary" name="destination" autocomplete>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Date and Time</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" name="travel_date_time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group mt-5">
      <button type="button" id="quote-btn" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Quote Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Comment below if map display is not needed -->
<div id="map"></div>

<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```